# Please help me optimize my code for a codechef problem!

Tags: java, optimization

I am solving this [question](http://www.codechef.com/problems/DCE05) on [codechef](http://www.codechef.com)! It is a simple problem, but my [solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/454585) times out! It seems it is not efficient enough! Please help me optimize it.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            System.out.println((int) (Math.pow(2, (int) ((Math.log(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()))) / (Math.log(2))))));
        }
    }
}
```

regards

shahensha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can cache `log(2)` in a variable, instead of computing it at every cycle
2. Instead of using `Math.log`, since you are working with integers, you can compute `log2` by using `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros` (see the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros%28int%29)), as `ceil(log2(x)) = 32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1)`

The `numberOfLeadingZeros` should be quite fast, as [the source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=it#ih5hvYJNSIA/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java&q=Integer.java%20numberOfLeadingZeros&l=1105) reveals that it just does a few bit-level operations to perform its work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this to find the next lower power of 2?  There are *way* faster ways to do that than calling any log functions, such as various bit tricks.  In general in 2's complement representation, the next lower power of 2 of positive `x` is the same as `x` with only `x`'s most significant bit set, and all other bits zero.

Edit: since you've confirmed you're looking for the next lower power of two, here's the canonical (branchless) bit hack:

```
/** The largest power of 2 <= x.
    Only valid for positive numbers. */
static int nextLowerPowerOf2(int x) {
    x >>>= 1;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: @Shahensha, edited to add bit hack for next lower power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a contest and you ask for help?? How can you be proud of you if the solution doesn't come from you?

Anyway, here is some hints:

1. Optimize your loop with pre-calculated values: Math.log(2) always give the same answer!
2. Use a StringBuffer in your loop and print only once, after the loop (to verify if it improve performance)
3. Math.Pow(2, INT), try with a Bitshift instead of Pow :)

[EDITED] My previous solution about Math.Pow was wrong, thanks Andrea

Comment: Math.Pow(2, (a/b)) != Math.Pow((a/b), 2). In any case, only the denominator could be pre-computed, as the numerator has to be evaluated.

Comment: @JPelletier..It is not a contest...These are practice problems on the site to hone my skills and I am a newbie...

Comment: @Shahensha Ok, I got confused with the "contest" publicity! I do not know codechef